# How segregate a pandas DataFrame based on column and groupby column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping, exploratory-data-analysis

input DataFrame:

```
*__name__  value*
A           1
A           2
A           3
A           4
B           2
B           3
B           4
B           2 
C           1
C           2
C           3
C           3
```

Expected output DataFrame:

```
*A  B  C*
1  2  1  
2  3  2
3  4  3
4  2  3
```

Let input df be A and the output df be B. I want the header of output B be the unique values of "**name**" column in df A and the value of the column should be populated with the corresponding values available in the input.

```
lst = []
value_Dict = {}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if df["__name__"][index] not in lstis below :
        lst.append(df["__name__"][index])
    else:
        continue

def Processor(val):
    values = [
        df["value"][index]
        for index, row in df.iterrows()
        if df["__name__"][index] == val
    ]
    value_Dict[val] = values
    return values

for i in metrics:
    print(i)
    value_Dict[i] = Processor(i)

new = pd.DataFrame(value_Dict)
```